# What is the VS Code keyboard shortcut to accept a highlighted change

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, git, visual-studio-code

I'm looking to review some changes using the keyboard. I can move between changes in VS Code using `ALT+F3` (*Show Next Change* aka `editor.action.dirtydiff.next`) or the previous change with `SHIFT+ALT+F3`.

This shows a "lens", highlighting the previous and current code with a local diff.

What I'd like to do then is to be able to press a shortcut to accept the change and stage it (in git terms). The shortcut that I found doesn't seem to work:

- `git.stageChange`  *Git: Stage Change*: the shortcut shows in the tooltip for the `+` button, but pressing the shortcut in the keyboard doesn't stage that change. It doesn't work when the lens is closed either.

Is there a command that would work via shortcut for this case?

[image: Screenshot of the lens region and button I'm interested in]

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to this I've been able to find is the "Stage Selected Ranges" command, which defaults to Ctrl-K, Ctrl-Alt-S.  However, you have to change the "when" expression in the keybinding  (as it only works in diff mode by default) and you have to select a range of lines that contains the change(s) you want to stage, as otherwise it will only stage the current line.

When used in conjunction with Alt-F5 and Shift-Alt-F5 (Go to next/previous change), you can navigate pretty well, except for the part where you can't really see the changes unless you're in diff mode.  So it's often simplest to just "Open Changes" for the current file (or click it in the Source Control view) and select+stage from there.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) key macro, which will cover all that by a simple keystroke.